# How to remove the title bar from a JFrame screenshot?

Tags: java, swing, screenshot, jframe

I'm capturing a screenshot image of a JFrame via a "double buffering" approach, per below:

```
public BufferedImage getScreenshot() {      
  java.awt.Dimension dim = this.getPreferredSize();         
  BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(dim.width, dim.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);            
  this.paint(image.getGraphics());      
  return image;     
}
```

where `this` extends JFrame. The image that I get has a blank strip along the top where the title bar was. What's the most straightforward way to capture an image of the contents of the JFrame without the extra space allocated for the title bar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use the [Screen Image](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) class. Just specify the content pane of the frame (or the root pane if you have a menu) as the component you want the image of.

Or your basic code should work, again just specify the content pane (or root pane) as the component you want to paint, not the frame itelf.

Comment: Thanks, picking the content pane was the key (in my case, it was actually the layered pane, but that's a project-specific detail). For some reason my original code doesn't work with the panes, but the Screen Image class does.

Comment: @Greg Harman, by default a layered pane is non-opaque, so the background of the image will be black. The ScreenImage class attempts to paint a background for you based on the background of the parent component.