# JFreeChart : how do you put multiple charts into a composite chart

Tags: java, jfreechart

In JFreeChart is there a notion of a composite Chart.

I need to layout several charts in a grid like arrangement.

Each chart in the grid needs to have its own separate title.

I would like to be able to save this composite chart into a png file

I would get a code snippet that explains how to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11895877/230513), `ChartPanel` can be placed in any desired Swing layout.
 The [example cited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7602126/230513) uses `GridLayout`. `ChartUtilities` has methods for rendering a chart as a `.png`. I see several approaches to getting a composite image:

- Use `Robot#createScreenCapture()` to image the layout, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3742841/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4530852/230513); the resulting `BufferedImage` can be saved using `ImageIO.write()`.
- Use `JFreeChart#createBufferedImage()` to render each chart and [impose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imposition) the individual images into a `BufferedImage` to create a single image, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2658663/230513).
- Implement the `Printable` interface to render the image in a graphics context, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A230513+implements+Printable).

[image]

Comment: many thanks for the answer ... it worked for me ... related question: I'd like to save the resulting composite chat into an png ... any suggestions ?

Comment: so what do I pass to the JFrame to the ImageIO? Thanks.

Comment: you might want to look at my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856325/plotting-a-locus-in-xy-space-using-jfreechart Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's too late to talk but, i want to ask something. Can you update these thermometers with timer? How?

Comment: @AloneInTheDark: Yes; use `javax.swing.Timer`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19833774/230513), or `javax.swing.SwingWorker`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13205322/230513).