# Showing two JFreeCharts on one page

Tags: java, pdf, graph, jfreechart

Im using JFreeChart to display two graphs on a PDF, but only one of them is showing and its showing at the bottom. Is there a sample code somewhere of how to show one graph at the top of the page and anoher at the bottom? Thanks.

Comment: Any help here: [JFreeChart : how do you put multiple charts into a composite chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805536/jfreechart-how-do-you-put-multiple-charts-into-a-composite-chart)?

Comment: Glad it helped. You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/163188). This would be especially useful if you can address the PDF aspect.