# JFreeChart Pie graph labels squishing

Tags: java, pdf, itext, jfreechart, pie-chart

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/34WJU.png]

As you can see from the picture, the labels for the arrows pointing to the sections of the pie graph are overlapping on the left side. Is there a way to shrink the font of the labels so more can fit? Or make them go out so they dont overlap?**strong text**

Comment: resize the whole graph panel

Comment: two of them have to fit side-by-side in a piece of paper.... if i could just delete those labels all together thatd be good too

Comment: In addition to the suggestion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15900169/230513), you can render the chart as an image and then down-sample.

Answer (score 0):

you can rotate chart by some angle by using following code

```
 JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart3D("World Polulation by Countries ", dataset, true, true, true);
            PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();

            plot.setPieIndex(0);

//          plot.setLabelFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.NORMAL, 12));
            plot.setNoDataMessage("No data available");
            plot.setCircular(false);
            plot.setLabelLinksVisible(true);
//          plot.zoom(200);
//          plot.setStartAngle(180);
//          plot.setLabelBackgroundPaint(paint);
            plot.setLabelLinkMargin(0.01);
            return chart;
```