# How do I get rid of the border made by capturing a jframe image to file?

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, awtrobot

So I made an application that creates a graphical timeline from a csv file. I have that part finished now I just need help getting the image "pretty". When capturing the image the border from the JFrame is captured too! **How do I make it such that the border is not captured? Or how do I get rid of it and keep the image size?**
[image]

Comment: Potential Duplicate of: [How to remove the title bar from a JFrame screenshot?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515902/how-to-remove-the-title-bar-from-a-jframe-screenshot)

Comment: Not exactly what I had in mind. I know how to get a screen shot. I'm looking to directly capture the image inside the frame

Comment: The other question mentions "a blank strip along the top where the title bar was"... isn't that part of what I'm seeing with the gray border around your image?

Comment: screen shots aren't exactly the greatest way to capture images. This has to be scalable

Comment: +1 @if_zero_equals_one, it does show you how to capture the image inside the frame. Did you read the accepted answer? The solution does not take a screen shot. And if you want to scale the image then you can use Image.getScaledInstance.

Comment: @camickr have you read the java file. All it equates to is a robot grabbing a portion of the screen. Also known as a screen shot. I would like an image writer if at all possible.

Comment: @if_zero_equals_one, yes I have read the java file, I wrote the code. Again did you read the accepted answer which shows how to create the image without using the Robot?

Comment: How about avoiding Robot altogether and get the component to paint itself on a buffer provided by You?

Comment: @Rekin, Read the answer given in the link provided, this is exactly what the Screen Image class does.

Comment: Your code is fine but there is a more practical way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BufferedImage image = (BufferedImage)createImage(getContentPane().getSize().width, getContentPane().getSize().height);
getContentPane().paint(image.getGraphics());
```

This is what I believe I was looking for.

Comment: It's really short. But... would you mind to modify your answer in such a way, that other people (me, for instance) can also use it? Where did you get this magic `createImage()` method? Which class contains it, or what is inside it?

Comment: It's a method that JFrame inherits from java.awt.Component.
it takes in the width and height and returns an Image.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example. Just to clarify your needs. Based on [solution of How to remove the title bar from a JFrame Screenshot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515902/how-to-remove-the-title-bar-from-a-jframe-screenshot/4515938#4515938).

The following program takes screenshot of its JFrame and writes it to the file.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/* Writes self screenshot on Screenshot button click. */
public class ScreenshotFrame extends JFrame {

    public ScreenshotFrame () {
        initComponents();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ScreenshotFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton screenshotButton = new JButton();

        screenshotButton.setText("Screenshot");
        screenshotButton.setToolTipText("Take my screenshot.");
        screenshotButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                writeImageToFile(getScreenshot());
            }
        });        

        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        getContentPane().add(screenshotButton);

        pack();
    }

    /* Modified method from pointed solution. */
    private BufferedImage getScreenshot() {
        Dimension dim = this.getContentPane().getSize();
        BufferedImage image =
                new BufferedImage(dim.width, dim.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        this.getContentPane().paint(image.getGraphics());
        return image;
    }

    /* Write image to png file in current dir.*/
    private void writeImageToFile(BufferedImage image) {
        try {
            File file = new File("JFrameScreenshot.png");
            file.createNewFile();
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", file);
        } catch (IOException ex) {/*do smth*/ }
    }
}
```

Does this what you want, [if_zero_equals_one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783280/if-zero-equals-one)? If not, maybe you could add some code to your question, that tries to do what you want.

P.S. Thanks to [Darien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315988/darien) and [camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131872/camickr), who pointed where to find the source for that
example.
Maybe this should be a comment. But it's clearer with such formatting.